# Runnable Jar (JavaFx) cannot find log4j2.xml using spring boot maven plugin as builder

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm in a bit of a pickle.

I have a master branch in git (Cant share sorry) that when built using the spring boot maven plugin, it works perfectly and nothing is wrong with it. Now i do some work to a branch and add stuff to it (only added 2 dependencies), everything works but the logging. It couldn't find my log4j2.xml configuration file and cannot produce a log file.

To my understanding (Please correct me if i'm wrong. I'm still trying to learn how to build runnable jars properly), when you build via maven spring plugin, it will just put all the required dependencies and classes (except for resources) in the executable jar file. You will then have to put the necessary resources on the programmed locations.

I don't know what i am missing. Its loading up my spring bean configuration outside the jar file properly (it doesnt crash during bootup). When i ran the executable through a terminal (java -jar App.jar), it doesnt contain any errors related to log4j2.

When i branched, i only added 2 dependencies/libraries (down below). I have my logger currently setup such that it should log on the same folder as where the executable is running.

Dependencies added since branch.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
   <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
   <version>0.1.54</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using version 2.8.2 for log4j2 both api and core.

Here is my spring boot plugin script in my pom.xml file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                <mainClass>
                        My Main Class here
                </mainClass>
                <layout>
                    JAR
                </layout>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm not setting up the log4j2.xml in the code. I just pray to the Gods it gets set properly during run time when i reference it. ie

```
private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CafQrCodeScannerMain.class);
```

and lastly here is my log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
            <File name="myFile" filename="${bundle:SomeFile:SomeFile.scanner.configuration.log.logFile}" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="myFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

its referencing to a property file that has the content
    someFile.scanner.configuration.log.logFile=AppName.log

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see what error you get in runtime. only two comments: do `mvn clean` when you switch between branches and check your dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: did that and still didn't work sadly. mind elaborating what to check when doing the mvn dependency:tree command? Please and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a configuration for it named log4j2.xml put it under src/main/resources. And check your pom.xml for a  log4j dependency

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Pleaes look at the docu https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html Scroll down to: How can I debug my configuration? It says if you set this Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE. as System Property it will print debug info about your configuration and this might help finding the cause for this issue.